# Cannot find module 'engine.io'

Tags: node.js

I am running

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

which is giving me this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'engine.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/harshil/chatapp/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I Have tried npm install -g engine.io,socket.io
npm update -g npm
but same and i always get this error

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket-chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter requires debug@'1.0.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket-chat-example/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.4
```

npm list gives me this output (showing only the error part)

```
└─┬ socket.io@1.2.0
  ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY debug@0.7.4
  ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY engine.io@1.4.2
  ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY has-binary-data@0.1.3
  ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY socket.io-adapter@0.3.1
  ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY socket.io-client@1.2.0
  └── UNMET DEPENDENCY socket.io-parser@2.2.2

npm ERR! missing: engine.io@1.4.2, required by socket.io@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: socket.io-parser@2.2.2, required by socket.io@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: socket.io-client@1.2.0, required by socket.io@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: socket.io-adapter@0.3.1, required by socket.io@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: has-binary-data@0.1.3, required by socket.io@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: debug@0.7.4, required by socket.io@1.2.0
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

The dependencies for `socket.io` should have been installed when you installed `socket.io` but it looks like that didn't happen or maybe stuff got deleted after it was installed. In any event, uninstall it and install it again:

```
npm uninstall socket.io && npm install socket.io
```

As a general rule, don't use `-g` with `npm install` unless you are installing a command line tool. Just install the dependency right there in your project.

Comment: Wow, you just saved my day man,